# AutoFill series of ComboBoxes - Java

Tags: java, date, jcombobox, autofill

I'm writing a simple program; one part of this program is a series of Comboboxes in which I have fed strings of Months(alpha), Days(numeric), and years(numeric). I would like to somehow get Java to pull the date, in terms of Months, Days, and Years, and then auto-fill these comboboxes with the correct day as per the system clock.

Here is some of my code:

```
public static final String[] MONTHS = {"January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
                                       "July", "August", "September", "October", "November",
                                       "December"};
public static final String[] DAYS = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", 
                                 "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", 
                                 "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", 
                                 "30", "31"};
public static final String[] YEARS = {"2015", "2014", "2013", "2012", "2011", "2010"};

Note to FORUMS: THIS ISN'T ALL THE CODE. I'VE JUST PROVIDED INFORMATION NECESSARY FOR THE QUESTION.

JLabel start = new JLabel("Start Date:");
if (shouldWeightX) {
c.weightx = .5;
}
c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
c.gridx = 0;
c.gridy = 1;
c.gridwidth = 1;
pane.add(start, c);

JComboBox MonthLong = new JComboBox();
if (shouldWeightX) {
    c.weightx = 0;
    }
c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
c.gridx = 1;
c.gridy = 1;
c.gridwidth = 1;
for(int i=0; i<MONTHS.length;i++) {
        MonthLong.addItem(MONTHS[i]);
    }
pane.add(MonthLong, c);

JComboBox DayLong = new JComboBox();
if (shouldWeightX) {
    c.weightx = 1.0;
    }
c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
c.gridx = 2;
c.gridy = 1;
c.gridwidth = 1;
for(int i=0; i<DAYS.length;i++) {
    DayLong.addItem(DAYS[i]);
}
pane.add(DayLong, c);

JComboBox YearLong = new JComboBox();
if (shouldWeightX) {
    c.weightx = 1.0;
    }
c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
c.gridx = 3;
c.gridy = 1;
c.gridwidth = 1;
for(int i=0; i<YEARS.length;i++) {
    YearLong.addItem(YEARS[i]);
}
YearLong.setSelectedItem("2013");
pane.add(YearLong, c);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't test this code.

```
    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
    int month = now.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    int year = now.get(Calendar.YEAR);

    MonthLong.setSelectedIndex(month);
    DayLong.setSelectedItem(Integer.toString(day));
    YearLong.setSelectedItem(Integer.toString(year));
```

In Java, variables usually start with a lower case letter.

Comment: This worked! Thank you very much. Also, I'm aware of the lowercase for variables, I'm editing some code for someone else, but in this question I said it was "mine". Whoops! Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You should get current time parts with **java.util.Calendar** class.

```
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
// months start with 0 
System.out.println("Year is: " + now.get(Calendar.YEAR));   
System.out.println("Month is: " + (now.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1));
System.out.println("Date is: " + now.get(Calendar.DATE));
```

then you can setSelectedIndex on your combobox at initialize step.

Also remember that, you do not have to use a for loop for adding these strings to the comboboxes. Just try that.

```
JComboBox<String> MonthLong = new JComboBox<String>(MONTHS);
```